# How do I detect when the address bar of mobile Safari hides on GWT?

Tags: javascript, ios, gwt, mobile-safari, mgwt

GWT 2.5.1 / 
MGWT 1.1.2

I added a resize handler to the Window, however no resize event is triggered when the address bar hides in mobile safari (tested on iOS 6x), The event is properly thrown if the handler is added natively with Javascript.

I'm not sure what event to expect when that happens. I don't want to rely on solutions that require setTimeOut's, native code or any other battery consuming workarounds.

Any ideas?

---

EDIT:

This behavior seems to be a bug on MGWT code. I already issued a report:
https://code.google.com/p/mgwt/issues/detail?id=300&can=4&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Estimate